# quanteda not creating corpus from corpusSource object

Tags: r, corpus, quanteda

I am using windows 7 with a 32-bit operating system with 4Gb RAM of which only 3Gb is accessible due to 32-bit limitations. I shut everything else down and can see that I have about 1Gb as cached and 1Gb available before starting.  The "free" memory varies but is sometimes 0.

Using quanteda - I am reading a twitter.txt file using the textfile() command which successfully creates a 157Mb corpusSource object.  When I take the next step to convert it to a "corpus" using the corpus() command R blasts through it and creates a very small empty file with four elements all containing 0's.....   Code and output follows:

```
twitterfile <- "./final/en_US/en_US.twitter.txt" 

precorp <- textfile(twitterfile)
corp <- corpus(twitterprecorp)
summary(corp)

Corpus consisting of 1 document.

              Text Types Tokens Sentences
 en_US.twitter.txt     0      0         0

Source:  C:/R_Data/Capstone/* on x86 by xxxxx
Created: Thu Aug 18 06:32:01 2016
Notes:   

Warning message:
In nsentence.character(object, ...) :
  nsentence() does not correctly count sentences in all lower-cased text
```

….Any insights on why this may be happening?

Comment: you use `twitterprecorp` instead of `precorp`

Comment: @HubertL points to an obvious issue that you need to check. Also is having a single document what you intended? Or does `en_US.twitter.txt` contain multiple "documents" in the form of multiple Tweets?

Comment: Thanks both of you.  I have updated the code as follows to make it simple I updated the code as follows and ended up with the same result:

Comment: twitterfile <- "./final/en_US/en_US.twitter.txt" 
precorp <- textfile(twitterfile)
corp <- corpus(precorp)  #this is generating a corpus with 4 empty items
summary(corp)
Corpus consisting of 1 document.

              Text Types Tokens Sentences
 en_US.twitter.txt     0      0         0

Source:  C:/R_Data/Capstone/* on x86 by WM7132
Created: Fri Aug 19 08:56:44 2016
Notes:   

Warning message:
In nsentence.character(object, ...) :
  nsentence() does not correctly count sentences in all lower-cased text

Comment: Ken, the en_US.twitter.txt file is one file of 238M tweets....I was creating a corpus with only one "document" so that I did not have to address which document in the corpus I was testing with.  My goal is to use the corpus to try out all the commands in the good tutorials that are provided before I move forward with other aspects of the project.

Comment: Try `nchar(texts(precorp))` -- what does it return? Also what is `packageVersion("quanteda")`?

Comment: Give the [**readtext** package](https://github.com/kbenoit/readtext) a try, it works very well with the new version of **quanteda** (v0.9.9), and is coming soon to CRAN.

Answer (score 0):

```
textfile()
```

is giving you character vector, with a single element for the entire file. You probably want to use

```
readlines()
```

as in:

```
precorp <- readlines(twitterfile)
```

this will give you a character vector with an element for each line in the file. corpus() will then treat each element of the vector as a document when creating your corpus.